# CLI or Text IDE based Audio/Music production software like LMMS?

Tags: windows-8, music-production, music-composing

There are softwares like [LMMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMMS) called the Audio or Music production softwares.

Their main task, or which I'm most interested in, is to create sound imitating the notes of music in differentg instruments, combined to form a melody or a tune.

I like [LMMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMMS), and there's [lots of softwares like it](http://alternativeto.net/software/lmms---linux-multimedia-studio/), but they're all mainly a point-and-click interaction based softwares and I find it tedious to work with the touchpad or mouse.

Is there a similar software but which could be used like a command line tool, or like a text-based IDE?

To make it more explicit, it should be able to do the following:

- produce sounds of different notes of various musical instruments, at least of a piano
- compose together and play a string of such musical notes
- save and load such a composition

Windows 8. Freeware preferred but open to paid as well.

Comment: Though you've outlined what you're after: could you please explicitely list your complete requirements (at least the must-haves)? Asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit old but I just came across this question :)
How about [lilypond](http://lilypond.org). It's cross-platform, (works on all versions of Windows as well). It's a text based music notation, can export to midi and pdf music sheet. Check it out for far more awesome features at http://lilypond.org.

Answer (score 1):

What about [sonic-pi](https://sonic-pi.net/), it is a free tool/IDE that supports a variety of different built in synths as well as the ability to code in your own.